# IsEnabled on Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm working on my first usercontrol ang got stuck on following problem
Changing the Value of binded property doesn’t even call the property getter (a textbox does)
What is the reason for this behavior?

```
<luc:IpTextBox x:Name="IpTxtBxIpv4Address"
    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
    IsEnabled="{Binding VmNicData.EnableIpSetting}" 
    Mode="IPv4Address"/>
<TextBox x:Name="TxtBxTest"
Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
IsEnabled="{Binding VmNicData.EnableIpSetting}"
Text="{Binding VmNicData.IpV4SubnetMask}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private bool _ipEnabled;
    public bool IpEnabled
    {
        get => _ipEnabled;
        set
        {
            _ipEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IpEnabled));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EnableIpSetting));
        }
    }
    private bool _dhcpEnabled;
    public bool DhcpEnabled
    {
        get => _dhcpEnabled;
        set
        {
            _dhcpEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DhcpEnabled));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EnableIpSetting));
        }
    }

    public bool EnableIpSetting => _ipEnabled && !_dhcpEnabled;
```

Thank's in advance

---

What I've done so far:

- My user control contains just some textboxes. I’ve got that DataContext = this; right after initializing my usercontroll.
- Setting the IsEnabled static to true or false has the expected effect on these texboxes.
- As soon as I try to bind it to the property it doesn’t work at all (even if Property is false at start texboxes aren’t disabled).
- I set a breakpoint at the property which doesn’t hit.
- I added this txtBxTest. To see if Binding works there. It does, breackpoint was hit.

---

> **Solved:** My mistake was to change the datacontext (DataContext = this in the constructor of my usercontrol). That broke my binding to parent.

Anyway thank you all for supporting

Comment: thats coz property changed os not fired in the right context raise a property changed for bound object

Comment: The code you posted looks nominally correct. So, whatever your problem, it's in the code you didn't post. Please fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Also, explain what you've done so far to debug the problem, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: What is VmNicData? Please show your *full* code.'

Comment: VmNicData is my ViewModel it has a couple of properties, no special magic. It is used as sub VM in an Master VM. Will add constructors to post

Comment: I still don't see the properties of the VmNicData class.

Comment: here they are ....

Answer (score -1):

You're binded to the "EnableIpSetting", but you are not calling OnPropertyChanged when it is updated.

You need to add your OnPropertyChanged logic to the EnableIpSetting as well.

Comment: _"you are not calling OnPropertyChanged when it is updated. "_ -- yes, they are. The view model class the OP posted implements `EnableIpSetting` as simply a composite of two other values, `_ipEnabled` and `_dhcpEnabled`, and it _does_ raise a `PropertyChanged` event for `EnableIpSetting` when either of those are changed (well, it _appears_ to from the code that was posted...since the OP didn't bother providing a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to confirm that).